# Aspnet conguration connection test fail after correct configuration

Tags: asp.net

I am building web form using VS2012Express edition. I am trying to implement SqlMembership provider. i did the congfiguration and all the neccessary objects are install.i can see the aspnetdb on my db server with all the objects.But when i try to create new user by goin to Project and ASPNET Configuration then Provider tab. i click the test connect and receive this error.`Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.`

I have done what this error message is telling and have look at several samples on MSDN site.   Could the problem be because i have both VS2010 Profession and VS2012 Express installed on my machine or am doing something wrong somewhere?
here is my webconfig.